# Android emulator and POS thermal printer

Tags: android-emulator

Is there any way that I can emulate USB POS thermal printer in an android emulator?

I ordered a printer online, but it will take some time to arrive. I was hoping to continue development in an emulated environment.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, Terminal Providers shouldn't allow Developers to Emulate their Devices. You have to use the corresponding Terminal for USB Debugging Proposes. Because SDKs are different from Terminal to Terminal Providers